# Output of SQL query as variable PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that connects to one of my SQL databases and runs a select command. I'm then trying to see what the output is of command but when I echo my results to a file I get "Resource id #5" and not a path like I'm expecting. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, I suspect it is the query or the result variable but I'm pretty new to php.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password");

if(!$connection) {
    system("echo 'ERROR! Unable to connect to MYSQL' >> /Reports/sqlerror");
}

$dbselect = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");


$query = "select p.path from path as p join file as f on p.pathid=f.pathid where f.filename like '$xfilename' and p.path like '/Data/original%'";

$result = mysql_query($query);


mysql_close($connection);

system("echo '$result' >> /Report/sqloutput");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Needed to use mysql_fetch as below.

$query = **mysql_query**("select p.path from path as p join file as f on p.pathid=f.pathid where f.filename like '$xfilename' and p.path like '/Data/original%'");

$result = mysql_fetch_row($query);
system("echo '$result**[0]**' >> /Report/sqloutput");